# How to add middleware class in padrino app

Tags: ruby, padrino

Could someone explain how to add a middleware class in a padrino application. The middleware class should enable trace point before processing an API request and disable the trace point after processing the API and serve the response to client.

Thanks in advance 
Mirza

Comment: Sinatra uses Rack behind it, so you are interested in creating Rack middleware. The topic is more or less covered here: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/middleware .

Comment: thank you @mudasobwa, checking it